# monkey test " Sending Flip keyboardOpen=false" cause IOException

Tags: java, android, testing, monkey

```
adb shell monkey -p com.eisoo.anycontent --kill-process-after-error --throttle 300 -s 600 -v -v -v 1000  > .\log.txt
```

After it finished in the log file I found many IOException like bellow:

```
"Sleeping for 300 milliseconds
:Sending Flip keyboardOpen=false
Got IOException performing flipjava.io.IOException: write failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)

Sleeping for 300 milliseconds"
```

From this information,I think this maybe caused by close soft keyboard,but I am not sure.

Please give me some advice ,no matter the root cause or some other suggestion on how to look for root cause.